# How to prove this binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Assume that X1 ∼ P(µ1) and X2 ∼ P(µ2) are independent. Prove that the conditional
distribution of X1 under the condition X1 + X2 = N to be the binomial distribution B(N, p),where p = µ1/(µ1 + µ2).
How to do it ? I tried moment generating function but how to transform it into a binomial form?

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ supposed to be Poisson distributed? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes they are Poisson distributed. I thought it can be solved by proving the M(t) of X1 is similar to M(t) of binomial distribution

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- First prove that $X_1+X_2\sim\mathsf{Poisson}(\mu_1+\mu_2)$ e.g. by finding an expression for $P(X_1+X_2=k)=\sum_{i=0}^kP(X_1=i\wedge X_2=k-i)$
- Now find an expression for $P(X_1=k\mid X_1+X_2=N)=\frac{P(X_1=k\wedge X_2=N-k)}{P(X_1+X_2=N)}$

Comment: Thanks, i am trying your way

Comment: i have more question why it is not P(X1+X2 = k) = P(X1 = i and X2 = k - i)

Comment: i mean why it's a sum

Comment: i have solved it by not using the summation, thank you~

Comment: E.g. $X_1+X_2=1\iff X_1=0$ and $X_2=1$ **or** $X_1=1$ and $X_2=0$. So the probability of LHS will be the **summation** of both probabities on RHS.